# Accessing Mapbox Geocoder Object

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have created a `MapboxGeocoder` object in my code and I'm curious if I can access/use it to reverse geocode elsewhere in the code. This, in an effort to get a formatted address from coords.

I created an object like so:

```
 const address = new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mbat,
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
    container: 'geocoder',
    countries: "us",
    bbox: [-83.726807, 31.784217, -78.013916, 35.415915],
    reverseGeocode: true,
}).on("result", function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I also have the `GeolocateControl` object in my code and I'm creating it like so:

```
map.addControl(
new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    // When active the map will receive updates to the device's location as it changes.
    trackUserLocation: true,
    // Draw an arrow next to the location dot to indicate which direction the device is heading.
    showUserHeading: true
}).on('geolocate', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
)
```

My question is, is there a way to access the `address` object within the `GeolocateControl` event handler to reverse geocode? I am imagining something to this effect:

`.on('geolocate', (e) => { console.log(address(e)) })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your geocoder instance is in scope, you should be able to use it in the event handler from `GeolocateControl`

I am not 100% sure about the `data` object in the `geolocate` callback, so inspect it to see how to pull out the lng/lat coordinates.

```
const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder(...)

map.addControl(
new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
  ...
}).on('geolocate', (data) => {
   const geocoder.query(`${data.coords[0},${data.coords[1]}`) 
})
)
```

Comment: Thanks @chris! Would you mind posting a link to the docs where the `.query` is outlined please?